# Kafka AdminClient DEFAULT_API_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG property not working as expected

Tags: apache-kafka

In my java application for kafkaProducer i created Admin and used this to list topics.

```
Admin admin1 = Admin.create(properties);
ListTopicsResult listTopicResult = admin1.listTopics();
```

When producer was not able to connect to broker thread get stucks at listTopic step.

To avoid this i have added `DEFAULT_API_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG` property and have set to 2000ms. so after 2s if producer is not able to connect to broker timeout should happen.

```
properties.put(AdminClientConfig.DEFAULT_API_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG,2000);
```

But this does not work as expected. even `DEFAULT_API_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG` with value 2000ms as property timeout didn't happen and thread was struck.

Is there any other way to achieve timeout or do we need to configure it in any other way?
Also is using `AdminClient` instead of Admin can have any impact.

Comment: Yes, you should be using AdminClient instead. As the constant says, `AdminClientConfig`. Also, `describeTopic()` can be used for the topics your producer actually will use rather than listing them all (which has higher chance of timeout for large clusters)

Comment: i tried AdminClient but faced similar issue, thread get stuck for more than 30s.
Is there any other way to check whether specific topic exist, where we can specify timeout for the call.

Comment: Read the AdminClient Javadoc? `DescribeTopicsResult describeTopics(TopicCollection topics,
 DescribeTopicsOptions options)`. In the options, it accepts a timeout. This returns a Map, where the values are Future objects you can call `get()` on to immediately block and catch exceptions

Comment: I have also faced that AdminClient creation itself fails.Is there any way to add timeout on this. I have added AdminClientConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG and AdminClientConfig.DEFAULT_API_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG. but the value is not getting picked. Also it taked more than 30second which is the default timeout -
These are the log
stackTrace='[java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method), java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1298), org.apache.kafka.clien     ts.admin.KafkaAdminClient.close(KafkaAdminClient.java:654), org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.Admin.close(Admin.java:153)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `new AdminClient()` alone cannot timeout since no requests are being made

Comment: It happens during AdminClient.create(properties)

Comment: The static create method is the same as the constructor. It shouldn't timeout until you actually make a network request